# Why is this file copying method slowing down

Tags: c#, file-io

I'm using code to copy a file from one location to another while generating a checksum on the fly. For small file the code functions properly but for big files for example a 3.8GB file it behaves strangely: After about 1 GB copied it suddenly slows down quite fast and then slows down more and more (fo example before the 1 GB is reached I observed about 2%-4% of the file being copied per second then when the 1 GB is reached it takes about 4-6 seconds per % of the file).

```
 int bytesRead = 0;
 int bytesInWriteBuffer = 0;
 byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1638400];
 byte[] writeBuffer = new byte[4915200];
 MD5 md5Handler = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
 using (FileStream sourceStream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    md5Handler.TransformBlock(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead, null, 0);
    FileStream destinationStream = File.Create(storageFileName);
    while (bytesRead = sourceStream.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length))
    {
        Buffer.BlockCopy(readBuffer, 0, writeBuffer, bytesInWriteBuffer, bytesRead);
        bytesInWriteBuffer += bytesRead
        if (bytesInWriteBuffer >= 4915200)
        {
             destinationStream.Write(writeBuffer, 0, bytesInWriteBuffer);
             bytesInWriteBuffer = 0;
             Thread.Sleep(50);
        }
    }
}
```

As was asked in a comment: There is no memory leak that would have been observable. The memory usage increases at the start of the method and then stays stable (total memory usage on the pc running it including when the mthod is run is in total 56% (for all applications in total running on that pc)). Total memory of the PC is 8 GB.

The application itself is 32 bit (takes up around 300 MB of memory itself) and the used framework is 4.5.

As an update after testing something a comment suggested: When I make the copy and cancel it via token and delete the file (all after the slowing down has started), and immediately begin a second copy process it is as slow as the other one was at the time I cancelled it (so the slowing down starts already before 1 GB there). BUT when I make the 2nd copy after the deletion finished it starts normally and only slows down at 1 GB.

Also Flushing the destination stream makes no difference there.

For the slowing down the copy is about 84MB per second at first and slows down to about 14MB per second at 1 GB.

As part of this question (not sure if better as a comment): Is it possible that this is not a C# related problem but instead "solely" a problem of the caching mechanisms from the OS? (and if so can be something done there)

As suggested I looked for the writecache of the OS and also let a performance monitor run.
Results:

- Different source hard drives and source desktops have the same result and also the same moment of the slow down
- Write cache in the OS (destination) is disabled
- Performance monitoring on the server where the destination lies shows nothing significant (write queue length is only once at 4 and once at 2, write time/idle time and also writes/second show nothing that suggests 100% usage of a cache or something else).

Further tests showed the following behaviour:

- If the copying itself is slowed down by doing a 200 millisecond `Thread.Sleep` after each write the average copy rate is 30 MB / sec which is constant
- If I instead put in a delay of 5 seconds (`Thread.Sleep`) after every 500 MB or 800 MB transferred, the slowing down occurs again and the waiting does not change anything at all.
- If I change the locations so that the source and destination are on my local hard drive (normally the destination is on a network folder) the rate is constant at 50 MB/s whereas the readtime is 100% and the bottleneck there, the writetime is way below 100%.
- Network transfer monitoring showed nothing that was unexpected
- Windows explorer has a transfer rate of 11 MB/s when copying a 3 GB file from the same source to the same destination (thus despite the slowdown happening in total the C# copying method is faster than windows explorer copying)

Further behaviour:

- According to monitoring things there was a constant stream to the destination drive (thus no speedy first part and a slowdown but the destination received the bytes constantly at the same speed).

As an adding to this: In total the performance for a 3 GB file is about 37 MB/s (84 MB for the first GB and 14 MB for the other GB).

Comment: Did you track the memory usage during file copying?

Comment: yepp memory does increase a bit in total when the method starts (as expected due to the large buffers) but then stays stable and does not increase strangely in any kind.

Comment: How much memory on your computer? You ran out of buffer.

Comment: @david.pfx The computer has a memory of 8 GB. which buffer do you mean?

Comment: Is you application 32 bit or 64 bit? By default, 32 bit application can only use 2G memory. You should track the memory usage of your application.

Comment: @matt the application only takes up around 300 MB in total (the 56% I mentioned in the post is the total memory usage of the PC itself). The application itself is 32 bit will include taht info and also framework 4.5 into the post

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct code snippet ? It won't even compile - you're using readBuffer before it is declared.

Comment: `Thread.Sleep()` seems odd. Why?

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar sry was a copy and paste error had to copy and paste snippet per snippet and partly write by hand as I use a few calculations to create the destination filename,... and a few additional stop conditions for the copy itself (which are not relevant for that problem though).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The thread.sleep I have added as I have observed that the harddrive was at a very high usage % when I used the program previously. With that sleep I decreased delays for other methods to access the harddrive and made it easier for other threads to do their job (got that idea from another stackoverflow post back then where someone had a similar problem that such a file ops almost locked down the computer)

Comment: Why do you copy the block only to write it out - why not just write out from ReadBuffer? Does it slow down also if you comment out the MD5 part?

Comment: That's the wrong solution though. You should low low-priority I/O instead.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError yes it still slows down (just tried it out). good point about the buffer. not sure atm if it still has a function there or if it is a remnant of a past version (that method grew over months as situations for usage changed considerably)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan what do you mean there?

Comment: I mean what I say. Use websearch to find out more. You can mark your thread as doing low priority IO. If nobody at normal priority is contesting you, you'll get the full IO perf. Otherwise you'll be interrupted and will have to wait.

Comment: Did you  try to destinationStream.Flush() after writing. Maybe it is faster at the beginning due to caching and slows down when it really has to write to HDD? What speed in MB/s did you actually achieve?

Comment: @Eiver I just tested it, makes no real difference (athough not sure if it starts 200 MB later to slow down or not). At about 1 GB the performance drops drastically. But testing your idea unvelied an interesting phenomenon there.   Post updated

Comment: It can, but we have insufficient data to be sure. For example I ran into problems when trying to achieve 1 GBit/s over .net socket (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/eae4f5y0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), so low level stuff could be a problem here. Try to experiment with buffer sizes. 84 MB/s is about right for a typical HDD, if you have execlusive-ish access while 14 MB/s is way to slow. Many performance issues must be taken into account. Is the source and destination file on the same physical HDD? Read and write operations might fight for HDD time. What about HDD fragmentation?

Comment: @Eiver sorry overlooked your comment. I updated my answer after doing a few additional tests. HDD fragmentation shouldnt be a problem currently on the server as its a relatively fresh one. Locally it also shouldnt be a problem as I optimized my HDD only a short while ago.

Comment: @Matthew What do you mean there? I'm using 1.6 MB read and 4.9 MB writebuffer there (in the first iteration I had a 32 MB write buffer).

Comment: The only things that have GB: The total size of the files involved and at about what stage of the copying the slowdown suddenly happens.

Comment: @Thomas never mind, I suck at math

Comment: @Matthew can happen that one overlooks things there what is irking though is that the slowdown is happening and nothing so far (not even from the answers) seemd to work there :/

Comment: why do you want checksum during copying?

Comment: @AndyH I need to get the checksum of the file that is being copied (as that is copied into a database for further usage). I'm using the standard checksum algorithms from C# and for a 3GB file they take almost 3 minutes to finish (which means if I dont do it during the file copying that you have the time for the copying and then the user sees "after processing" (or foreprocessing depending on order) for over 3 minutes which is inacceptable from the user side

Comment: Put in additional test results

Answer (score 4):

Just a guess but I feel it's worth a try. it may be related to the file system's space allocation algorithm. At first it cannot predict the size of the file. It allocates a space, but after a while (1GB in your case) it reaches the bounds. Then it probably tries to move the neighbor file to make a contiguous storage. Check this out: https://superuser.com/a/274867/301925

In order to make sure, I'd suggest you create a file with initial size as in the following code, and log the time elapsed in every step. (I don't have an environment to try it out, correct it if it contains syntax errors)

```
int bytesRead = 0;
int bytesInWriteBuffer = 0;
byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1638400];
byte[] writeBuffer = new byte[4915200];
//MD5 md5Handler = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider(); exclude for now
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
long fileSize = new FileInfo(filePath).Length;
using (FileStream sourceStream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    //md5Handler.TransformBlock(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead, null, 0); exclude it for now
    stopwatch.Start();
    FileStream destinationStream = File.Create(storageFileName);
    stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Create destination stream: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    stopwatch.Restart();
    // trick to give an initial size
    destinationStream.Seek(fileSize - 1, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    destinationStream.WriteByte(0);
    destinationStream.Flush();
    destinationStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Set initial size to destination stream: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    while (true)
    {
        stopwatch.Restart();
        bytesRead = sourceStream.Read(readBuffer, 0, readBuffer.Length);
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Read " + bytesRead + " bytes: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        if(bytesRead <= 0)
            break;
        Buffer.BlockCopy(readBuffer, 0, writeBuffer, bytesInWriteBuffer, bytesRead);
        bytesInWriteBuffer += bytesRead;
        if (bytesInWriteBuffer >= 4915200)
        {
            stopwatch.Restart();
            destinationStream.Write(writeBuffer, 0, bytesInWriteBuffer);
            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Write " + bytesInWriteBuffer + " bytes: " + stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            bytesInWriteBuffer = 0;
            //Thread.Sleep(50); exclude it for now
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Was an interesting and also good idea. When I tested it the phenomenon was the same though at about 1-1.3 GB it slowed down considerably.

Comment: So sadly no effect on the phenomenon.

Answer (score 1):

You could be seeing the effect of OS write-caching on disk IO. You can disable this for hard drives - get the properties for your drive (not the drive letter. Right click a drive letter, check the hardware tab, select a disk, click properties, click 'change settings', then the write-cache policy is on the Policies tab. Reboot just to be sure).

edit 1.

ok, not filesystem cache io. What happens if you enable jumbo frames on the network? You'll need to do this on both client and server network driver settings,and potentially the switch too (depending on switch). Throughput should increase. 
Its possible the OS is throttling the network bandwidth - try also disabling the QoS service in your network driver settings (client only I think, but it never hurts to do both sides)

Then you could stick wireshark on and see what SMB packets are being sent over the network and what happens at the slowdown transition.

Comment: I've updated the question about the result of what I saw when I checked your suggestion about the write cache and also one additional test with different client machines:  Write caching from OS side wsa deactivated already the whole time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is probably hardware related, and not c# related. When you start your second copy action after delete, there is probably a cache, which is still full. Depending on your disk type, hd/ssd/hybrid/raid you can have very different results. To further investigate you should install some low level monitoring tools and ask your hd vendor for specifications on read/write cache.

Comment: I've updated the question with the results of a performance test made by the sys admins here. Strangely there was no exceptional result for write cache length or disk operations (even though all really points to some sort of caching issue as a similar phenomenon result is questiioned here as I saw: http://superuser.com/questions/315134/why-does-my-flash-drive-speed-slow-down-when-copying and there it was also cache related)

Answer (score 0):

I strongly agree with other answers to this post; your problem isn't probably in the C# code.
There's many reasons that may produce such behavior and some of them are already listed within the below answers and comments. In order to identify the cause of your problem let's make a checklist and rule out its tasks one by one.

Let's copy the same file you are working on from the same source and destination tested with         your c# code but this time using the windows copy. we'll observe the bandwidth speed.

1- If everything went normal and no slow down
   ** then we have a C# coding problems(unlikely to occur)

2- If a slow down was observed. we may have three possible cases :
   2.1- Possible disk problem at source or destination:
   ** to rule out this possibility you should make some tests on the source and destination's disks;i suggest using this tool: 
 http://crystalmark.info/?lang=auto
  and post the results here. and when i say disk problem i don't necessarily means a physical damage.disk problems may affect reading and writing. 
   2.1- Possibly a networking problem
      ** network bandwidth test should be conducted
   2.3- Possible OS caching mechanism
      ** OS related configuration; many suggestions has already been posted within this thread.

As you can see, there's many reasons that may cause that behavior. what I've posted is a diagnostics tree that will let you rule out unlikely scenarios and focus on the remaining issues.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't quite follow why you would craft such complex copying algorithm, with such large r/w buffers, checksum and the odd looking sleep. I had written my own tests with all default settings of BCL codes and common local hard-drive.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        long length=0;
        using (var source = new FileStream(args[0], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        using (var dest  = new FileStream(args[1], FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            source.CopyTo(dest);//default buffer size 81920
            length=source.Length;
        };
        var span = (DateTime.Now-dt).TotalSeconds;
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Time: {0} seconds; speed: {1} byte/second", span, length/span));
    }
```

Here's the result on my local hard drive:

```
68 MB,  94 MB/s
80 MB,  94 MB/s
232 MB, 86
680 MB, 48
980 MB, 63
3.5 GB, 37 
5.9 GB, 36
```

Platforms: .NET 4.5, Release, AnyCPU; Windows 7 64 bit; Intel Xeon 2.67GHz; Memory 12 GB

While in my tests, we can see the over 1 GB the speed is slower, however, not as so dramatically as shown by Thomas (84 MB/s vs 14 MB/s). We should also consider the the fragment situation of the hard-drive could contribute significant variables. A more scientific test should be constructed in a de-fragmented disk, with files small or large located in similar radius.

Using File.Copy gives similar results, probably because File.Copy uses similar algorithm like mine. Modern OS like Windows is quite smart, the default settings in .NET Frameworking and Windows mostly give you best performance; unless you know the OS and the target system very deeply, twisting the settings even with over complex algorithm could hardly give you better and consistent performance.

So the complex algorithm does not seem to work well with the spinning nature of hard-drive. While I had heard of some poor hard-drive did not performance well with large files, however, why don't you test your program/algorithm on other computers with different types of hard-drive? If your program has consistent strange performance on different drive drives, low end or high end, then you can be sure that it is the algorithm having the problem.

Nevertheless, hardware architecture do have significant impact on overall performance, but not discriminating small and large files dramatically out of constraints of the basic spinning nature. For example, copying on RAID, or between 2 physical hard-drives, specific algorithm might gain performance significantly through asynchronous read/write or even concurrency. But that's another subject then.

Comment: I fear that you overlooked one point there in my post. I have at start 84 MB/s and then it goes down to 14 MB/s but only after 1 GB is up). Thus in total ((14*2GB + 84 * 1GB) / 3 = 37.3 GB / second thus it is the same total result as your routine has (as the 14 MB/second are for the remaining 2 GB). Good point there though with your answer as that seems like it is either intrinsically OS/hardware related OR C# related (although C# directly uses a dll from the OS for the file accesses as far as I  know).

Comment: On also an interesting result when I copy the same file with windows explorer it takes more than 5 minutes with a rate of 11 MB/s

Comment: .NET in this regard just does good memory management in addition to the native calls to Windows API. The developers of Windows and CLR had made a lot efforts to make applications gain decent performances without the much needs of writing complex algorithms by application developers. The IO operations are closely monitored by OS and CLR, and your smart algorithms might be circumvented by such monitoring. As you had seen, your smart long codes and my dump and short codes had basically similar performance for large files.

Comment: Unless your application is dedicated for copying large files always, what we had observed is likely by design for good, for overall performance of the system which should prioritize reading and writing "small files".

Comment: or the head portions of large files.